# .net Maui background data fetching no page refresh

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, maui

i am creating a .net Maui/Xamarin mobile application, it is an application to sell items. there is 2 main steps

1- seller send a product for sell
2- clients start to send their price offer for that product

now after the seller send the product for sell, he should start receive the price offers from clients at they send it.

my issue is that i want the page shows the offers from clients as they send it automatically without clicking any button or doing any page refresh. MVVM and observables will refresh my list for example after the data is received. but how to make the app go and get the new offers from client in the background and then update the observables in the viewModel.

does anyone have any idea on the best way of doing this other than the one mentioned about

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the below options

1. Use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter) which works on the publishing & subscribe technique.
2. Use [Delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) which helps us to share references of methods, which you use to update the details.
3. Use [SignalR](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDr0Hx67guk), This video explains how to use SignalR.